# create the variable link as a hyperlink javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

create a hyperlink with the variable link

```
<html>
<body>
<center><h1> retrive data</h1></center>
<h1 id="head1"> </h1>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter your unique id" id="pass"/>
 <input type = "button" value = "submit" id="but" onclick="myfunction();"/>


<script>
   var pass;

function myfunction()
{
   pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  document.writeln(pass);
  document.writeln("<br>");
  document.writeln("<br>");
  document.writeln("<br>");
  document.writeln("<br>");
  var passwordToLookFor = pass;
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users");
var query = ref.orderByChild("password").equalTo(passwordToLookFor);
query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(child) { // loop over the results
    console.log(child.key);
    console.log(child.val().user_name);

    var link = child.val().user_name;
    document.writeln(link);
    });
});
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

***i want to create the value of link as a hyperlink***
i want the hyperlink to be created once when the function is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just looking for how to make it an anchor tag?

```
<script>
   var pass;

function myfunction()
{
   ...

    var link = child.val().user_name;
    document.writeln("<a href='"+link+"' target='_blank'>"+link+"</a>");
    });
});
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: can you help me with adding  target="_blank" in the anchor area?

Comment: updated - you can just add it in as part of the string - no variable or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `a` dom element like this:

```
let link_el = document.createElement('a')
link_el.href = link // assuming link holds the value of the href you want
```

Then insert it into the dom wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly and the `link` variable contains the actual address you want to navigate to, then this will work. First simply set an ID on the div you want to populate with links:

```
<div id="target-div"></div>
```

Then populate it like so (I just created an array for demo purposes, but this would be your snapshot.forEach:

```
var links = ['link1', 'link2', 'link3']

var targetDiv = document.getElementById("target-div");

links.forEach(function(link) {
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.href = link;
  anchor.innerText = link;
  targetDiv.appendChild(anchor);

  var br = document.createElement('br');
  targetDiv.appendChild(br);
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/csnuh7rd/2/